# if condition false also it is redirecting to sign up page can any one help in this

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, if-statement, redirect

```
public IActionResult Index()
`enter code here` {
    HttpContext.Session.SetString("Tenant", _tenant?.ToString() ?? String.Empty);
    var tenant = HttpContext.Session.GetString("Tenant");
    if (new Guid(tenant) == new Guid())
    {
        return RedirectToAction("SignUp", "Register");
    }
    else
    {
        return RedirectToAction("SignIn", "Register");
    }
}
```

Comment: What did you think would happen?  Both paths do exactly the same thing

Answer (score 0):

if Index the same controller then you can use RedirectToAction("SignIn")
else you can use Redirect("Register/SignIn");

Comment: I altered code but then also it is redirecting sign up page

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).